# Switch voltage output with Zener diodes in series

Tags: power-supply, diodes, zener

I´m trying to produce a power supply that can give an output of both 24V and 12V.
I want to switch between these two voltages with a signal of 5V, when the signal is low i want to get out 24V and then when it´s high i want an output of 12V.

I have been experimenting with two Zener diodes in series and try to bypass one of the diodes to get the lower voltage. I am not sure if this thery will work totally i practice. I got it to lower about 1V, maybe the transistor doesn´t saturate completely? Any ideas how to easy switch between the two voltages?

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is some extra information from the comments surrounding the project and an updated schematic:

So it´s suposed to be a power supply to a sensor that operates at 5V, the sensor sends out a 5V signal that should toggle a relay that operates at 24V. Since I want a low power consumption I want to lower the voltage to 12V when the relay doesn´t need to be on. Hope this clarifies a bit.

[image]

Comment: What voltage is coming in to the bridge?  That looks like some kind of capacitive dropper.  Your 5V signal would have no ground in common with the transistor, so no go.  The whole circuit is just icky.

Comment: What's the input voltage to the rectifier? Seems like it's directly connected to the grid. Am I correct? What's the required output current?

Comment: 230Vac input and output is about 40mA. The 5V signal is taken from the same circuit, I have a LDO that transform the 24/12 to the signal. So the ground would be the same, wouldn´t it?

Comment: You should state a **crucial** parameter: How much **current** will the output need to deliver.  Also you do not mention your input voltage. Also note that the 5 V signal for switching has to be applied between X3-3 and the ground on the right (emitter of T4). That ground is not available on the X3 connector.

Comment: *LDO that transform* Hmm, LDOs don't transform, they **regulate**. Please show the circuit as complete as possible including anything that's "obvious" to you. It happens that someone takes a lot of trouble to switch between 12 V/ 24V in order to save some power while in the end, there's no difference but the design uses more components than actually needed.

Comment: Okey, will try to edit the schematic to clarify! Yes you are right that i need to lower the power consumption, it doesn´t matter if more components are needed.

Comment: OK, then explain **why** you need lower power consumption, the thing is mains powered so it is not like you'll drain a battery. If you want really low power consumption use a **bi-stable** relay, these only need power when changing state (some extra electronics might be needed though). Your "shorting a 12V zener" might actually result in **more** power to be consumed as the impedance as seen from the mains will decrease at 12 V.

Comment: You can make the **whole circuit more energy efficient** by removing the 12V/24V switching and dimensioning C1 (make C1 a smaller value) such that when the relay is **off** you get 24 V (or a bit more) across C2 and when the relay is **on** the voltage can drop to 12 V. That costs less components and actually does save power. I have seen this scheme being used in similar circuits. There is **no need** to switch between 12 V / 24 V if you just make the capacitive dropper such that the voltage drops when the relay is on.

Comment: There is a regulation that says that electronic equipment thats in ''idle'' mode should have a lower power consumption than 0.5W, so would simply like to go under that limit. Will se if i maybe can change the dimension of C1, but from what i have seen it changes the output current from the power supply. Maybe a bi-stable relay would be a suitable option further down the road.

Comment: I'd just ditch that linear regulator and go for a buck regulator. It will be efficient enough to not need to drop the 24V, more efficient than the linear regulator at 12V even.

Comment: You are aware that that circuit must be fully enclosed to protect the user, and you cannot allow external connections to it?  There is no isolation from the mains.  All parts of that circuit must be treated as if they carry the full mains voltage.

Comment: Yes I have been thinking of doing a it with a switching regulator and yes the whole circuit will be enclosed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foeroG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the signal is 5V the output will be 12VDC. Otherwise it will be 24VDC.

NOTES:

- Vin must be at least 30V and RZ should be calculated according to minimum input voltage, \$V_{i-min}\$: \$RZ[k\Omega]=(V_{i-min}-24)/8\$. Its power rating should be calculated from maximum input voltage, \$V_{i-max}\$.
- Q1 may need a heatsink. Because, if the input voltage is 30V and the output voltage is 12V, total power consumption of Q1 will be about 0.75W at a load current of 40mA. So a power transistor in TO-220 package (e.g. BD243) and a proper heatsink should be used.

Comment: The voltage is not going to be 12V and 24V. Because of D1 and Q1, the voltage will be 1.2V above zener voltage. So it's going to be 13.2V and 25.2V

Comment: @Chupacabras nope. Please look again. Without D1 the output will be one Vbe below total zener voltage (11.4V or 23.4V). Adding D1 will will nullify the Vbe of Q1.

Comment: I looked again. You are right :) I was wrong about the polarity of Vbe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your circuit conceptually.

Not sure why you picked 39K for the base resistor of T3- perhaps you have a big bag of them.. anyway, the peak current through the transistor with 240VAC/60Hz applied to the circuit will be a bit less than \$C\cdot dv/dt\$  or about 51mA if I did the derivative correctly (do the calculation yourself, using whatever numbers make sense in your application). So your base current should be in the 2-3mA range- implying more like 1.5K.

Or replace the BJT with a small logic-level MOSFET.

While you're at it, calculate the base resistor for the relay driver transistor and make sure you're giving it enough drive for whatever the coil current is.

Comment: Yeah got lots of 39K that i need to get rid of, I think that this might solve the problem that i´m having! Thanks for the advice will try it later when I have the time!

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sens, as energy saving is concerned, because what you gain by limiting the voltage down to 12V will be lost through the zener. Normaly if IC1 is a 5V voltage regulator, it should deal with this issue intelligently and you wouldn't need to worry about it.